# ibm mobilefirst v7.1 is giving error while opening console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

This is not working for me,when I click preview it opens a blank text file with error "file missing would you like to create one" and console is also not opening..!

Comment: Please update with more details, what are you trying to do ? what error do you see in console ?

Comment: Put up a screenshot. And what the server logs show